# Batch file with more than 9 options for user input

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I have this simple shortcut script but when I select a number that is higher than 9 it opens authorization manager and does not recognize the second digit. I have played around with the settings but to no avail and Google isn't much of a help with this one.

```
@title Microsoft Management Console
@echo ┌───────────────MAIN MENU─────────────────▄
@echo │Choices:                                 █
@echo │                                         █
@echo │ 1. Authorization Manager                █
@echo │ 2. Certificates Local Computer          █
@echo │ 3. Certificates Current User            █
@echo │ 4. Component Services                   █
@echo │ 5. Computer Management                  █
@echo │ 6. Device Manager                       █
@echo │ 7. Disk Manager                         █
@echo │ 8. Event Viewer                         █
@echo │ 9. Local Users Manager                  █
@echo │10. Performance Manager                  █
@echo │11. Print Server                         █
@echo │12. Services                             █
@echo │13. Shared Folder Manager                █
@echo │14. SQL Server Config                    █
@echo │15. Task Scheduler                       █
@echo │16. Windows Firewall                     █
@echo │17. Exit                                 █
@echo │                                         █
@echo └▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█

@set /p userinp=Type the number of your choice: 
@set userinp=%userinp:~0,1%
@if "%userinp%"=="1" azman.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="2" certlm.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="3" certmgr.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="4" comexp.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="5" compmgmt.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="6" devmgmt.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="7" diskmgmt
@if "%userinp%"=="8" eventvwr.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="9" lusrmgr.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="10" perfmon.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="11" printui /s /t2
@if "%userinp%"=="12" services.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="13" fsmgmt.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="14" sqlservermanager10.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="15" taskschd.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="16" wf.msc
@if "%userinp%"=="17" exit
```

Comment: You could state `@echo off` at the very first line so you don't need to put `@` before every single line; and check out the `choice` command for single-key-stroke-selections (you could use letters from `A` to `Q` in your case); the advantage is, it does not accept anything else than the predefined options; type `choice /?` in a command prompt window to find out how it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
@set userinp=%userinp:~0,1%
```

to

```
@set userinp=%userinp:~0,2%
```

In your original version, you are requesting 1 character starting from the 0th character. The first number represents the starting character index, and the second one represents the number of characters to get.

Comment: Thats it! Awesome. I can't select the answer for 7 minutes but I'll leave the page up and select after lunch.